# How does a Queryable Load work in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, linq-to-objects, sharepoint-clientobject

Could anybody help me to understand what kind of work is going behind the scene, when LINQ is used for retrieving SharePoint objects. For [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx), I can use a code like this:

```
private IEnumerable<List> newLists;

var dt = new DateTime(2010, 3, 20);
var query = from list
            in clientContext.Web.Lists
            where list.Created > dt && list.Hidden == false
            select list;

newLists = clientContext.LoadQuery(query);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How does it work?

How does request look like?

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx) I found:

> When you use the CSOM, you can write LINQ queries against client-side
>   objects, such as lists and Webs, and then use the ClientContext class
>   to submit these queries to the server. It's important to understand
>   that when you take this approach, you are using LINQ to Objects to
>   query SharePoint objects, not LINQ to SharePoint. This means that your
>   LINQ expressions are not converted to CAML and you will not see the
>   performance benefits that are associated with CAML conversion.

So, I was little bit confused, because I thought, that LINQ expression is transformed to Caml request. I can't understand how does it work. How can I watch details of request while executing `ExecuteQuery()` method? Could you please recomend me any tools for watching requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SP uses CAML internally: SP runtime converts Linq to CAML and send it via Soap request, or REST statement (if you are using RESTful services): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx (with examples);

See more here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798464.aspx

and this can be helpful: http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/sharepoint-2010-data-querying-options-server-om-vs-client-om-vs-rest-vs-linq-vs-search-api/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and really helpfull links! But as I found from MSDN documentation LINQ expressions are not converted to CAML :( I have updated my question with this note, please review. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: "Linq to SharePoint" converts Linq to CAML (+ special DataContext class generated) but CSOM uses Linq (expression tree) serialization/deserialization over http (like Ria services, like linq over wcf) and real query execution performed on server

Comment: Gr8, thanks! That's what I looked for. And could you please recomend me any tools for watching requests? I want to see request and response when I invoke ExecuteQuery() method.